# Angularjs script template doesn't work

Tags: angularjs

I'm very newbie to angularjs, and I followed the [script](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script) document of angularjs to created a very simple script tag of template, however it does't work at all, below is the code and [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/15839/).

```
<div ng-app>   
    <table>
        <ng-include src="tpl.html"></ng-include>
    </table>
    <div ng-include src="tpl2.html"></div>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="tpl.html">
        <tr>
            <td>ACBC</td>
        </tr>
    </script>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="tpl2.html">
        test
    </script>
</div>
```

Any problem with my code?

Comment: ng-include's `src` is  angular expression evaluating to URL. If the source is a string constant,  you have to wrap it in single quotes,

Answer (score 1):

put the url in single quotes

```
src="'tpl.html'"
```

`

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tpl.html">
    <tr>
        <td>ACBC</td>
    </tr>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="tpl2.html">
    test
</script>
```

see fiddle update 
`http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/15840/

Comment: I see, but I encountered another problem see the updated fiddle [Inline Link](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/15842/), I'd like to repeat that included template, it seems doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You missed `<td></td>` element :)
This is how you should implement your code

```
<div ng-app>
<table>
   <tr ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5,6]">                     
       <td>
           <ng-include src="'tpl.html'"></ng-include>
       </td>          
   </tr>
</table>

<div ng-include src="'tpl2.html'"></div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="tpl.html">
        <td>ACBC</td>
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tpl2.html">
    test
</script>
```